# Identity User Verify User

Tags: asp.net, identity

I am in the process of upgrading a Winform from using Membership to Identity. All I need is a simple function that will verify the user as put in via the username and password in 2 text boxes.

I have migrated all the tables in the database.

I have created a connection string the app.config file.

All the existing (inherioted) code is in VB and almost everything I can find here or elsewhere is C#, but nonetheless I have written this funtion to verify that the login and password are what is in the database. I have hard coded the ID copied from the database because using FindByName was coming up with an error, which is the same error even if I use the FindById method.

Private Function VerifyUser(userName As String, password As String) As Boolean
Dim connectionString As String
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance)

```
    connectionString = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("ApplicationServices").ConnectionString
    Dim identdb As New IdentityDbContext("ApplicationServices")
    Dim myUserStore As New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)(identdb)
    Dim myUserManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(myUserStore)
    Dim bRtn As Boolean = False
    Dim usr As IdentityUser

    usr = myUserManager.FindById("14ED6529-01E3-4BDE-8377-10482DF24BCD")
    bRtn = myUserManager.CheckPassword(usr, password)
    Return bRtn
End Function
```

This error occurs at the line

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'MethodCallTranslator' threw an exception.'
Inner Exception
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')

I was under the impression that identity will use the key Id by default.

Does anybody knwi what I am missing? DO I have to specify the key the table is using (which is Id) and if so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question.
I converted the above code from VB.Net to C# and it all works.

```
public bool VerifyUserNamePassword(string userName, string password)
    {
        var usermanager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new IdentityDbContext("ApplicationServices")));
        return usermanager.Find(userName, password) != null;
    }
```

The VB.Net code is exactly the same but just in VB syntax. I have no idea why C# works but VB doesn't but it does.

So now to convert the other thousands of lines of code to C#. Yay!!!

Comment: I did finally get it working with VB.Net. I found the real issue was that the VB project was using EntityFramework 6.0.0. And because I created a new C# project it actually used the latest EntityFramework 6.4.4. Once I upgraded the VB project to EntiutyFramework 6.4.4 and removed the RegisterFactory line my errors went away.

Comment: And I also removed all references to EntityFramework in the app.config file.